# How do I define a variable and add a unit to it and display it in elementor rendering?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

i use this code:

```
protected function content_template() {
    ?>
    <ul>
    <#
    if ( settings.list ) {
        _.each( settings.list, function( item, index ) {
        #>
        <li>
            <# if ( item.link && item.link.url ) { #>
                <a class="؟" href="{{{ item.link.url }}}">{{{ item.text }}}</a>
            <# } else { #>
                {{{ item.text }}}
            <# } #>
        </li>
        <#
        } );
    }
    #>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```

I would like to add the following to the code above:

1. one: Define a variable named i before function javascript.
2. two: A
   unit is added to the item variable every time the JavaScript
   function is executed.
3. three: How do I insert the variable i into the
   tag class attribute a instead of the question mark?

thank's for answer
please help me...

Comment: You cannot mix javascript and php like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _.each callback function already has the parameter, index, which contains the number of the current iteration.  So I believe you already have what you need.  Just try replacing the question mark with {{{ index }}}